# How to use the 'AppIntro' package in android?

Tags: android, package

I am looking for a way to create a First-Start Tutorial for an App, and I found the following package: [AppIntro](https://github.com/apl-devs/AppIntro) for that.

Probably a nice package, but I have no clue on how to use it. Some pieces of how to use it are given, but no full downloadable example project.

Is there an example app somewhere on how to use this `AppIntro` package, or do I have to experiment on my own for days in order to learn how to use it ...?

There is an example project [given here](https://github.com/apl-devs/AppIntro/tree/master/example/src/main), but upon compiling this project I see nothing that actually resembles what I was expecting. I was expecting what is shown [the original page](https://github.com/apl-devs/AppIntro) in the first images. Some pages you can 'slide', with some dots on the button showing on which tutorial page you are.

Actually, some working hints come from

- the video tutorial given on the main page of the library
- and using the class `SampleSlide` given somewhere in the `example` section.

However, at the end, the Intro never starts, as the `SharedPreferences` `firstStart` is always set to 'false'. Now I need to figure out a way to 'reset' the SharedPreferences...

Comment: scroll down to the "Usage" section. It will tell you how to use it.

Comment: How funny! Of course I did scroll down! It describes some parts, but none of the Fragments, how to use it in connection with the actual main activity, how to make sure to have the FirstLaunch activity launched only once....

Comment: What, for example, is included in the method `addSlide`? Not obvious to me...

Comment: @Alex Have you checked the video tutorial?

Comment: @AnixPasBesoin: Does this REALLY explain how to use it? I mean, a video tutorial can be nice, but when its about CODE, then do I have to type hundreds of code lines from paused video screens or what??

Comment: @Alex It's just 12 mins you know, and you can skip the first 2 mins.

Comment: Ok, then. I watch the video, stop it from time to time, try to recreate the content, play on, pause again, type and type...  Will take a while...

Comment: @AnixPasBesoin: So, basically I got it working, but how to make the Intro Screen to come up only once? The solution given does not seem to work, I do not see any Intro screen , but directly my MainActivity Screen: https://github.com/apl-devs/AppIntro/wiki/How-to-Use#show-the-intro-once

Comment: If you find issues with the code, the tutorials, or the readme, I suggest you talk to the people who are responsible for them directly.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

1. Do not follow the code exampled given on the main page
2. Follow the Video tutorial
3. Download the not-working example code
4. Find the code for `SampleSlide` somwehere in the example code
5. Insert a button in order to 'reset' the shared preferences
6. Use this code to 'reset' the shared preferences:

   ```
   public void resetPrefs(View view) {
       //  Make a new preferences editor
       SharedPreferences getPrefs = PreferenceManager
           .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());

       getPrefs.edit().clear().commit();
       // changes layout
   }
   ```

When I have some time I will put the COMPLETE and FULLY WORKING code in here later ...

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I implemented it:

1. Added the dependencies in root build.gradle and app-level build.gradle.
2. Added a java file named *IntroActivity.java* and inserted the necessary code.
3. Along with the above java file, I created respective XML layout
   files and called them in the `addSlide` function.
4. I also added the BaseSlide.java (or [SampleSlide.java](https://github.com/apl-devs/AppIntro/blob/master/example/src/main/java/com/amqtech/opensource/appintroexample/util/SampleSlide.java)) for
   Fragments.
5. Finally, added the Manifest declaration.